# How to access child elements inside a TableRow in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout file has a structure like:

```
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout >

       <LinearLayout >
          <IconTextView />            
       </LinearLayout>

       <TextView />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The above linear layout is repeated 4 times in a table row -->
</TableRow>
```

None of the elements inside the table row have IDs for some reason. So how do i access the `IconTextView` and `TextView` inside every `TableRow`?

I access each child (outer LinearLayout) inside every `TableRow` with the help of `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` functions.

Now, I want a similar way to access different elements inside the child (for example `IconTextView` and `TextView`)

Comment: try to put tags and use findviewbytag

Comment: @DIVA As I am a greenhorn in android programming, can you please elaborate it for me ;)

Comment: Lets discuss on chat

Comment: did u solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set the id's and use them to identify the views, as you are creating your Views programatically you should be able to assign id's to them easily.

A solution would be to set the IconTextViews id's to 1 and the TextViews id's to 2, you can retreive them with ease by calling View.findViewById(int id) on the direct parent container - in this case each TableRow. So to retreive each IconTextView, call currentTableRow.findViewById(1).

Preferably you would use getChildCount() and getChildAt() to loop through your TableRows. Of course you will have duplicate id's in your view hierarchy, but if you call findViewById(id) relatively to your TableRow, it won't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

u can use in xml
android:id="@+id/diplay" 
then in main java file u should write

```
public class Arithmatic2 extends ActionBarActivity {
 TextView display;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arithmatic2);

    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.diplay);
        }
```

Comment: I cannot assign IDs in xml as i want to form the UI through code so as to reduce redundancy